# Incorrect indentation when using an if statement inside a lambda expression

Tags: c++, visual-studio, indentation

I'm using VS2022, and pasting the [code from the following example](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/cpp/cpp/lambda-expression-syntax?view=msvc-170#code) will write: Even if you press `Ctrl + K + F` to sort all, it will be sorted like below.

```cpp
// This code is my VS2022
// ...

for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&evenCount](int n) {
  cout << n;
if (n % 2 == 0) {
  cout << " is even " << endl;
  ++evenCount; 
}
else {
  cout << " is odd " << endl;
}
  });

// ...
```

```cpp
// This code is MSDN example
// ...

for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&evenCount] (int n) {
  cout << n;
  if (n % 2 == 0) {
     cout << " is even " << endl;
     ++evenCount;
  } else {
     cout << " is odd " << endl;
  }
});

// ...
```

If I use an if statement inside a lambda expression, automatic indentation is not correct. Not regular.

Is something wrong with my VS2022 settings?

Comment: Please make your title a short summary of the problem or the question, then give us all the details and ask the actual question itself inside the main body.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have supplemented the post according to you comments.

Comment: My VS2022 (version 17.2.5) is auto-formatting this snippet exactly like the MSDN sample.

Comment: You can also use clang-format from visual studio, this will give you a lot more control on how you want your formatting to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar problems hava been reported on Developer Community. Try VS2022  version 17.5 preview 5.0.

Link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/auto-indentaion-not-working-in-the-lambd/10201118

Comment: Perfectly solved :D